# How to write a sequence of XQuery function calls?

Tags: xquery, basex

I have a lot of such assignment statements `let $tmp :=`, because otherwise I get the error message "Incomplete FLOWR Expression, expecting return":

```
declare function module:import($xmlsrc as xs:string, $conn as xs:anyURI) {

  let $root := module:getXml($xmlsrc)
  
  (: Table01 :)

  let $id := 2
  
  let $tmp := trace("Table01")
  
  let $sqlstmt := "insert into Table01 (rel1,rel2,rel3,rel4,rel5) values(" 
       || $id || ", 
    '" || $root//myns:ftr[@n='abc']/myns:ftr[@type='p1'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:ftr[@n='abc']/myns:ftr[@type='p2'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:ftr[@n='abc']/myns:ftr[@type='p3'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:ftr[@n='abc']/myns:ftr[@type='p4'] || "')"
               
  let $tmp := sql:execute($conn, $sqlstmt)
       
  (: Table02 :)

  let $id := 3
  
  let $sqlstmt := "insert into Table02 (rel1,rel2,rel3,rel4,rel5) values(" 
       || $id || ", 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p5'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p6'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p7'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p8'] || "')"
               
  let $tmp := sql:execute($conn, $sqlstmt)

  (: more tables to import to :)
    
    return()
};
```

Is there another way, i.e. without those assignment statements, to meet the XQuery requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you want a function that is called only for its side effects, and you don't actually want to return anything from the function.

Functions with side-effects aren't well supported by the XQuery language specification, and you're very much in "vendor extensions" territory. So the answer is going to depend on which XQuery implementation you are using.

You can call the functions without binding the results to variables, for example

```
declare function (...) {
    module:getXml($xmlsrc),
    trace("Table01"),
    sql:execute($conn, "insert into Table02 (rel1,rel2,rel3,rel4,rel5) values(" 
       || $id || ", 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p5'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p6'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p7'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p8'] || "')"),
    sql:execute($conn, "insert into Table02 (rel1,rel2,rel3,rel4,rel5) values(" 
       || $id || ", 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p5'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p6'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p7'] || "', 
    '" || $root//myns:div[@n='abc']/myns:xyz[@type='p8'] || "')")
};
```

With both formulations the language spec offers no guarantee about order of execution, which is rather critical in a case like this; for such guarantees you will need to turn to vendor documentation.

Comment: However, in my code example, the order of the variable bindings also determines the order of the calls to the functions with side effects on the right side of the let statements. So the functions with side effects are executed from "top to bottom" as specified in the source code, and not non-deterministically.

Comment: That may be the case with one XQuery processor, but not the case with others. In Saxon, a variable that is never used is never evaluated, so none of your sql:execute functions would be called at all, and certainly not a defined order. As I say, you're in vendor-defined territory when it comes to side-effects.

Comment: But what if I call `module:import($xmlsrc as xs:string, $conn as xs:anyURI)` inside a `try{} catch{}`, shouldn't all functions be called that could generate an error (which is the case for `sql:execute`)?

Comment: No, writing try/catch says what should happen if there's an error, but it doesn't force the processor to do extra work to detect errors that wouldn't be detected otherwise. For example, 'some $x in (12, 4, 0) satisfies 100 div $x > 3` can return true (rather than an error) whether or not you enclose it in a try/catch.

Comment: In the end, I'm really glad now that I found a solution to the practical problem of using XQuery to shovel data from XML into an SQL database. Even if it looks syntactically strange. I think I would have let it go if I had known exactly the execution model of XQuery. But thanks for sharing your theoretical knowledge with me.